# What is the best way to use multiprocessing CPU inference for PyTorch models?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pytorch

I have to productionize a PyTorch BERT Question Answer model. The CPU inference is very slow for me as for every query the model needs to evaluate 30 samples. Out of the result of these 30 samples, I pick the answer with the maximum score. GPU would be too costly for me to use for inference.

Can I leverage multiprocessing / parallel CPU inference for this?
If Yes, what is the best practice to do so?
If No, is there a cloud option that bills me only for the GPU queries I make and not for continuously running the GPU instance?

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way to get better performance would be to reduce the model as much as possible.

One of the most promising techniques is quantized and binarized neural networks. Here are some references:

1. https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.05279
2. https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.02505

Answer (score 0):

You could try to optimize your inference with [OpenVINO](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_overview.html). OpenVINO is optimized for Intel hardware but it should work with any CPU. [Here](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_performance_benchmarks_openvino.html#bert-base-cased-124) are some performance benchmarks for the BERT model.

There are a few already optimized BERT models available in the [Open Model Zoo](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/blob/master/models/intel/index.md#question-answering), so you don't need to convert your own and there is a full [tutorial notebook](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_notebooks/blob/main/notebooks/213-question-answering/213-question-answering.ipynb) on question answering with BERT.

However, if you would like to use your model you can follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_notebooks/tree/main/notebooks/105-language-quantize-bert) with optional quantization step for better performance.

Disclaimer: I work on OpenVINO.

Answer (score -1):

You can try out the following:

Make use of Intel Pytorch for better performance. Refer https://github.com/intel/pytorch to install pytorch with Intel Optimized functionalities.

You can use Intel Optimized Python libraries. i.e while creating your environment make sure you pass the intel channel. Eg: conda create -n **env_name** python=3.6 **-c intel**. Also, you can install specific libraries with Intel channel.

Another option is to try out using Multi-Node distributed training using Horovod for PyTorch. Refer the link https://github.com/horovod/horovod#pytorch for further details.